# Why does this error arise :java.net.PlainSocketImpl.checkNotClosed(PlainSocketImpl.java:116)?

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking

I am working with Sockets on Android and keep getting this error

logcat:

---

```
[xiaomi-mi_4i-a98ed4b2]: E/File couldn't be stored: java.net.PlainSocketImpl.checkNotClosed(PlainSocketImpl.java:116)
[xiaomi-mi_4i-a98ed4b2]: W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
[xiaomi-mi_4i-a98ed4b2]: W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.checkNotClosed(PlainSocketImpl.java:116)
[xiaomi-mi_4i-a98ed4b2]: W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.getInputStream(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
[xiaomi-mi_4i-a98ed4b2]: W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.getInputStream(Socket.java:363)
[xiaomi-mi_4i-a98ed4b2]: W/System.err:     at com.rkp.musictest1.wifi.datatransfer.WifiSocket.receiveFileSocket(WifiSocket.java:264)
[xiaomi-mi_4i-a98ed4b2]: W/System.err:     at com.rkp.musictest1.wifi.datatransfer.WifiSocket$4.run(WifiSocket.java:249)
[xiaomi-mi_4i-a98ed4b2]: W/System.err:     at com.rkp.musictest1.wifi.datatransfer.SimpleAsynTask$simpleTask.doInBackground(SimpleAsynTask.java:65)
[xiaomi-mi_4i-a98ed4b2]: W/System.err:     at com.rkp.musictest1.wifi.datatransfer.SimpleAsynTask$simpleTask.doInBackground(SimpleAsynTask.java:23)
[xiaomi-mi_4i-a98ed4b2]: W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
[xiaomi-mi_4i-a98ed4b2]: W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
[xiaomi-mi_4i-a98ed4b2]: W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
[xiaomi-mi_4i-a98ed4b2]: W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
[xiaomi-mi_4i-a98ed4b2]: W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
[xiaomi-mi_4i-a98ed4b2]: W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: thanks @GhostCat , but i am still confused as to what led to the socket or some other FileDescriptor be closed.

Comment: You closed the socket and then continued to use it. Possibly you are unaware that closing the input stream or output stream closes the socket.

Comment: Thats it..thanks @EJP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look into the source code yourself - it is [enter link description here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/5.0.0_r2-robolectric-1/java/net/PlainSocketImpl.java#PlainSocketImpl):

```
private void More ...checkNotClosed() throws IOException {
    if (!fd.valid()) {
        throw new SocketException("Socket is closed");
    }
}
```

fd is a FileDescriptor; and for that we find; regarding the valid() method:

*Returns:
true if the file descriptor object represents a valid, open file, socket, or other active I/O connection; false otherwise.*

So, long story short: something is closed that should not be closed. But further debug is *hard* without seeing the code / activity that leads to this error.

Hope that is enough to get you going for now!